# TextView bounds must get clipped by rounded ImageView

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, clip

I am trying to achieve this effect.
The blue area is a textView inside a rounded ImageView.

[image]

I tried doing it with clipRect, but no succes.

Any other idea?

Comment: check this https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Image.md

Comment: `a textView inside a rounded ImageView.` A TextView can't be put **inside** an ImageView. And why do you need an ImageView at all? You can simply use a TextView with a circular background.

Comment: @Rotwang The big circle (the ImageView) is a user image that can be uploaded from phone or taken from Facebook. What I am trying to achieve is that drawable background of the TextView to clip around the ImageView border.

Comment: Again... you don't need to use an extra ImageView, since TextViews can have background images.